# Is it possible to use WSO2 ESB / AS and Push notifications with Cometd?

Tags: push-notification, wso2, push, cometd, wso2-esb

Is it possible to make push notifications from a web application deployed in WSO2 AS to a client who wants to initialize the long polling connection requesting against an ESB proxy that redirects to the web application in the AS?

The flow could be something like that:

```
Client long polling request (Browser) -> WSO2 ESB proxy -> WSO2 AS web application (Cometd)

Asynchronously, WSO2 AS web application sends push notifications to the client through the ESB proxy.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I answer myself. It is possible. I got it with a Cometd 2.x servlet and a browser as a client who starts the connection via javascript.

Here's a very clear example about how to make it:
http://docs.cometd.org/tutorials/